# @value with static field in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a class in which I want to read a property file and initialize a static field using @value, but this always comes as null

```
public class MyClass{

@value(${my.value})
private static String myValue;
}
```

So my question here,

1. Is there any workaround to do this like using a static setter.
2. Why it does not work with static field, if I change it to non static it starts working :(

Comment: @BobTheBuilder that does not answer why it does not work with static field it only suggests a workaround

Comment: You can read more here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-3845